# PHP Printing to Remote Printer

Tags: php, sockets, printing

I have a remote POS printer it uses the ESC/POS protocol.
I have a PHP app running that prints messages:

```
    $texttoprint = "Samuel is a legend \nHello. \nTest123";
    $texttoprint = stripslashes($texttoprint);

    $fp = fsockopen("10.1.1.100", 9100, $errno, $errstr, 10);
    if (!$fp) {
        debug("$errstr ($errno)<br />\n");
    } else {
        fwrite($fp, "\033\100");
        $out = $texttoprint . "\r\n";
        fwrite($fp, $out);
        fwrite($fp, "\012\012\012\012\012\012\012\012\012\033\151\010\004\001");
        fclose($fp);
    }
```

It works but only sometimes, if i run the code it works around 1 in 10 times but it is not hitting the error so I don't know why its only printing sometimes.

Comment: For starters, you're ignoring the return value. ["`fwrite()` returns the number of bytes written, or `FALSE` on error."](http://php.net/fwrite). Also, why not use just one write call?

Comment: @user113215 I have checked that it returnes the corect number of bytes for each fwrite().

Comment: @user113215 having only one fwrite() fixed it. Don't know why.
If you post it as an answer, I will happy accept it.
If not I will answer it myself later.

Comment: Strange! That was only a stylistic suggestion on my part :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using only one fwrite() fixed this issue.
Thank you @user113215.
If anyone knows why I would love to know.